# How to use HTTP request UrlFetchApp.fetch(), instead of Built-in Advanced Services in Apps Script

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this code to change the name of a file in Apps Script using Apps Script Advanced Services

```
Drive.Files.update({ title: "testing" }, "15MPNng9YALbnAIAdwo54v6ESUvMhr2teHCL1QtN_ZJkY4aqWnsv6QVvB");
```

And it works great!  It changes the name of the file successfully.  Except I need to use it in contexts where the Google Drive API Service is not enabled.  Therefore, I am trying to complete this same task using an HTTP request, [which can be done](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced), and which I have done on other tasks, but I am struggling to get the syntax right for this one.

So here is the code I have written to do this:

```
function changeFileName(fileId = "15MPNng9YALbnAIAdwo54v6ESUvMhr2teHCL1QtN_ZJkY4aqWnsv6QVvB", newName = "testing") {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}`;

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  const query = {
    name: newName
  }

  const params = {
    method: 'patch',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(query)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

and the response is:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "15MPNng9YALbnAIAdwo54v6ESUvMhr2teHCL1QtN_ZJkY4aqWnsv6QVvB",
  "name": "TT - User Template",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script"
}
```

And the file name is not changed.  Here is the [documentation for the method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update)

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks!

*Updated code to reflect suggestion by Master to resolve name key difference between v2 and v3, but the issue persists.

Comment: What's wrong with ``function changeFileName() {
  DriveApp.getFileById("fileid").setName("MyFile")
}

Comment: @Cooper, DriveApp.getFileById() cannot access script files that are contiainer bound to a spreadsheet, but the Drive Advanced Service can.

Answer (score 0):

`Drive` advanced service uses `v2`. Your http call makes the call to `v3`. One important difference between `v2` and `v3` is that the `title` field has been renamed to `name`.

```
const query = {
  /*Modified from title for v3*/name: newName
}
```

Comment: I've updated the query key in the original post's code per your suggestion, but the response is the same and the file has not been renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the "Test this Method" tool at the [documentation site](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update)
and see the cURL output to see what I was missing (expand the tool to full screen to see this)

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{}' \
  --compressed
```

It turns out "Content-Type": 'application/json' is a required header for this to work.  The "Accept" header seems to be optional because it works without it.

Here is the functioning code in apps script:

```
function changeFileName(fileId, newName) {
      const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}`;
      const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      const query = {
        "name": newName
      }
      const params = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        payload: JSON.stringify(query)
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
      Logger.log(response);
    }
```

@TheMaster was also correct in that I needed to change the "title" key to "name" for v3 of the Drive API.